# Data Binding in Data Grid with collectionviewsource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an ObservableCollection of class

```
Public class Object
{
  public string Name;
  public Employee Employee;
}

public class Employee
{
  // few properties
}
```

Here is my XMAL code for CollectionViewSource:

```
 <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsTasks"
                          Source="{Binding Reels}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

Here is my DataGrid code:

```
   <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsTasks}}"/>
```

Now  CollectionViewSource having PropertyGroupDescription on Name and I want to bind my DataGrid with Employee property of CollectionViewSource .

Comment: Can you post the code you are discussing here. `ObservableCollection`, `CollectionViewSource`. Also class name is `Object`?

Comment: @MohitSinghBora: Can you show what `Reels` is. What is its type?

Comment: ObservableCollection of Object is named as Reels in ViewModel

Comment: @XAMlMAX: _"CollectionViewSource will NOT work with ObservableCollection"_ -- since when? I use the two together all the time. What are you talking about?

Comment: @XAMlMAX: `CollectionViewSource` is a wrapper with filter around a collection. It could be any collection that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Since the `CVS` is already implementing the `INPC` and the `OC` is doing that as well, won't the two clash? I was trying to find a blog where I have read to avoid using those two, but unfortunately I can't. I will retract my comment @PeterDuniho

Comment: @XAMlMAX: _"CVS is already implementing the INPC"_ -- `CollectionViewSource` implements neither `INotifyPropertyChanged` nor `INotifyCollectionChanged`. You can get an instance of `ICollectionView` from `CollectionViewSource`, which does implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, but without a source collection that also implements that interface, it wouldn't be as useful; only changes to the view would be reflected, and not also changes to the underlying collection. Far from conflicting with each other, `CollectionViewSource` works best when the source implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know, if i understand your question correctly.

View:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsTasks" Source="{Binding List}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid >
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsTasks}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="EmpID" Binding="{Binding Employee.ID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="EmpDeportment" Binding="{Binding Employee.Department}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Model.Root> List { get; set; }

    public ViewModel() {
        List = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Model.Root> {
            new Model.Root {
                Name = "Peter",
                Employee = new Model.Employee {
                    ID = 1,
                    Department = "IT"
                }
            },
            new Model.Root {
                Name = "Hans",
                Employee = new Model.Employee {
                    ID = 2,
                    Department = "accounting"
                }
            },
            new Model.Root {
                Name = "Bilbo",
                Employee = new Model.Employee {
                    ID = 3,
                    Department = "ceo"
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Model {

        public class Employee {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Department { get; set; }
        }
        public class Root {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

And the result:
[image]